# Why can't I hold back a box?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Consider the following code ([on playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8de788fb4783fa431c34&version=stable)) :

```
// calling this function move the ownership of nbr to is_even
// at the end of the function is_even doesn't give the ownership back
fn is_even(nbr: Box<i32>) -> bool {
    *nbr % 2 == 0
}

fn main() {
    let integer = Box::new(42);
    if is_even(integer) {
        print!("is even ");
    }
    println!("{}", integer);
}
```

I get the following error message :

```
example.rs:10:17: 10:24 error: use of moved value: `integer` [E0382]
example.rs:10   println!("{}", integer);

example.rs:7:13: 7:20 note: `integer` moved here because it has type `Box<i32>`, which is non-copyable
example.rs:7    if is_even(integer) {
```

I don't understand why. Ok, when I call `is_even`, I give the ownership to this function, but at the end of `is_even` that function doesn't need the ownership any more. It is a immutable (read only) transfer of ownership so we are sure it is not deleted when `main` hold back `integer` -> it seems safe to use it back.

Still there is this error. Why and what is the workaround ?

Comment: This and other funny rust-stuff is - so I theorize - related to the way they approach things. Now, obviously is_even() could work with the semantics you suggest. Yet, a different implementation of is_even() which would pass the argument to some other function(s) which might or might not persist or change the value or have them treated in other threads would change the semantics. Not sure if my explanation is correct - but this is how I explain this unintuitive behavior to myself.

Comment: @BitTickler: that's mostly it, yeah. If you pass the argument as `Box<i32>` then you're *giving it away*, and the `is_even` function is free to mutate it, pass it around, and do what it wants, confident that the `main` function isn't going to be able to use it after the function ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to retain ownership of your box, then you must have `is_even` **borrow** it, rather than take ownership of it. Here is a working version of your code:

```
// calling this function move the ownership of nbr to is_even
// at the end of the function is_even doesn't give the ownership back
fn is_even(nbr: &Box<i32>) -> bool {
    **nbr % 2 == 0
}

fn main() {
    let integer = Box::new(42);
    if is_even(&integer) {
        print!("is even ");
    }
    println!("{}", integer);
}
```

Note that `is_even` now takes a reference (with a `&`) to the Box, and we have to pass in a reference (again, with a `&`) when we call the function. Finally, the function now operates on a reference rather than a value, so we need to add another `*` to de-reference it before we can operate on it.

However, it's a good rule of thumb to avoid using non-mutable references to values that own their contents (such as `String` or `Vec` or `Box`). The function could be re-written as the following:

```
fn is_even(nbr: &i32) -> bool {
    *nbr % 2 == 0
}
```

This works with *any* reference to an integer, not only ones that are in `Box`es.

Comment: <from someone on irc>There is no such thing as an immutable ownership  you can move it into a mutable binding and fiddle with it all you want.

Answer (score 6):

> when I call `is_even`, I give the ownership to this function

Exactly. You've transferred ownership. You don't have it any more and the function will do what it wants. In this case, it will free the memory, so you **definitely** can not use it after the call.

> that function doesn't need the ownership any more

Which is why it is dropped.

> It is a immutable (read only) transfer of ownership

That doesn't exist. You completely transfer ownership, there's no halfway about it.

> so we are sure it is not deleted

Actually, we *are sure* it is freed, and that is a very good thing. Rust manages that for us so you never have to ask "who should free this?"

So how do you fix it? That's simple: pass a reference to the inner value, not the whole box. This *borrows* the value (mutably or not, up to you) and ownership is not transferred.

```
fn is_even(nbr: &i32) -> bool { ... }
```

Comment: I made a rust post and you didn't edited it ! Are you in a good shape ? :p

Comment: In fact, the transfer of ownership isn't *ever* immutable. Once you are given ownership via a move, you have free reign to outright change it to mutable if you want, whenever you want, though you have the choice to not invoke that privilege. Playground: http://is.gd/B6rHuM